# Pregunta sobre tiempo y modo verbal en las oraciones condicionales

Tags: subjuntivo

E. Montolío en su artículo "Las construcciones condicionales" habla de tres tipos de oraciones condicionales básicas (reales, potenciales e irreales) y pone algunas combinaciones posibles de los modos verbales, por ejemplo *si+indicativo + indicativo* (*Si estudias aprobarás*.), etc. 
He encontrado algunos ejemplos que no „encajan“ en ninguna pauta de los que ella ofrece. ¿Me  podríais por favor explicar por qué es así?

**1) si+imperfecto de indicativo + condicional compuesto**

> Habrían podido meterme a la cárcel, si me pescaban.

(¿Por qué no "si me hubieran pescado"?)

**2a) si+subjuntivo imperfecto + subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto**

> No tenía novio y me puedo imaginar que si lo tuviese no me lo hubiera
>   dicho.

(¿Por qué no "si lo hubiera tenido no me lo hubiera dicho"?)

**2b)**

> Si fuera rico, no me hubiera ido a Australia.

(¿Por qué no "no me iría a Australia"?)

**3) si+imperfecto de subjuntivo + condicional compuesto**

> Si fuera mi hija, quizá ya la habría matado.

(¿Por qué no "la mataría"? ¿Se puede combinar el imperfecto de subjuntivo con el condicional compuesto?)

**4) si+subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto + indefinido de indicativo**

> Tuvo suficiente leche para alimentar muchos niños más, si así lo
>   hubiera deseado.

(Entiendo el sentido de la frase pero cuando consulto las combinaciones de Montolío y no encuentro esta pauta, estoy confundida... ¿Sería posible utilizar el indicativo aquí – "si así deseaba"?)

**5a) si+imperfecto de indicativo + subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto**

> Iba a saltar, lo hubiera hecho si él no me lo impedía.

(Aquí me parece que la parte "lo hubiera hecho" puede ser sustituida por "lo habría hecho" pero no estoy segura).

**5b)**

> El sexo pudo salvarme si ella hubiese contestado: sí.

(¿Por qué no "El sexo hubiera podido salvarme si ella hubiese contestado: sí."?)

Y para coronarlo todo,

**6) si+pluscuamperfecto + presente de indicativo**

> La verdad es que si hubiera seguido un momento más así me caigo de
>   cabeza en la rayuela.

(Aquí no tengo ni idea porque no entiendo en absoluto cómo se puede combinar estas dos formas.)

¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

> 1) "Habrían podido meterme a la cárcel, si me pescaban."

Aunque formalmente este uso es incorrecto, la tendencia a reemplazar el subjuntivo por indicativo de esta manera es común en el registro hablado. En mi propio dialecto yo he escuchado eso y también sustitución de condicional: "Si hubiera sabido antes te avisaba con tiempo", "Si me pescaban me metían a la cárcel". Mal que mal es como los hablantes se expresan. En portugués coloquial también la he escuchado, no sé si en otras lenguas romances también ocurre, pero no me extrañaría.

> 2a) "No tenía novio y me puedo imaginar que si lo tuviese no me lo hubiera dicho."

Aquí hay un embrollo de tiempos verbales que quizá el hablante se sienta tentado a simplificar para no repetir. Si fuéramos a lo más formalmente correcto debería ser "... si lo hubiese tenido no me lo habría dicho."

> 2b) "Si fuera rico, no me hubiera ido a Australia."

Como en el ejemplo anterior aquí hay sustitución de subjuntivo por condicional. Esta sustitución es extremadamente común y ni siquiera sé si los gramáticos la consideran todavía incorrecta. En cuanto al uso del pluscuamperfecto, otra vez hay una simplificación de tiempos: quizá sería más correcto decir "Si hubiese sido rico no me habría ido a Australia" o bien "Si fuera rico no me iría a Australia". Así como está, de todas formas, el significado está claro: tanto la hipotética riqueza como la ida a Australia ocurrieron en el pasado.

> 3) "Si fuera mi hija, quizá ya la habría matado."

Esta frase me parece totalmente correcta. La construcción con pluscuamperfecto y el adverbio *ya* me sugiere que hay una acción pasada implícita a la cual esta hipótesis precede en el tiempo. "Si fuera mi hija quizá la mataría" sugiere que el hablante se propone realmente matar a alguien en caso de que se cumpla la condición; el ejemplo como está sugiere que la hipotética decisión no está actualmente siendo considerada por el hablante, sino que podría haberlo sido en un tiempo anterior.

> 4) "Tuvo suficiente leche para alimentar muchos niños más, si así lo hubiera deseado."

Preguntas si se podría utilizar "...si así lo deseaba". Creo que se entendería bien y no sonaría incorrecto, pero por como está construido el ejemplo, queda claro que el "tuvo suficiente leche" es algo que ya ocurrió y terminó, y por lo tanto el "alimentar muchos niños más" es algo que sólo puede ser deseado con anterioridad a ese otro suceso pasado (pretérito pluscuamperfecto).

> 5a) "Iba a saltar, lo hubiera hecho si él no me lo impedía."

Tal como supones, podría ser mejor decir "lo habría hecho", pero aquí está otra la sustitución de condicional por subjuntivo. A mí me llama más la atención que se utilice el pretérito imperfecto del indicativo en vez del subjuntivo compuesto ("impedía" en vez de "hubiese impedido"). Éste es el mismo caso que en el ejemplo 1).

> 5b) "El sexo pudo salvarme si ella hubiese contestado: sí."

Yo también habría preferido un compuesto en vez de un indefinido. Vale lo mismo que en el ejemplo 4).

> 6) "La verdad es que si hubiera seguido un momento más así me caigo de cabeza en la rayuela."

Aquí no sé qué decirte. Está claro que algo no está "bien" con ese presente de indicativo, pero también ocurre que este tipo de frase la escucho todo el tiempo, de gentes de todas las edades y clases sociales, en todos los ámbitos excepto los muy formales. Habría que investigar si este fenómeno de simplificación extrema está reconocido y descripto. (Prometo volver y editar si encuentro algo.)

P.S.: un ejemplo de la sustitución del subjuntivo por pretérito imperfecto del indicativo en la prótasis de una oración condicional. Dos párrafos seguidos en [una nota política](https://www.lacapital.com.ar/opinion/los-presos-y-los-privilegiados-n1521347.html) en el diario *La Capital* (Rosario, Argentina, 10/dic/2017).
[image: subjuntivo reemplazado por indicativo]

Answer (score 2):

Esto debería ser un comentario más que una respuesta, pero por su extensión me veo obligado a usar este formato.

Estoy en gran parte de acuerdo con la minuciosa respuesta de Pablo, y es todo un desafío agregar al menos algo a sus completas explicaciones, que a mi modesto entender son casi perfectas.

Me da la sensación de que Aurora siente la obligación de ceñirse a los tipos convencionales de oraciones condicionales y no admite las perfectamente correctas "oraciones condicionales mixtas". Del mismo modo, como ha observado Pablo, noto a Aurora algo renuente a aceptar ciertas formas y combinaciones de tiempo de uso coloquial.

1) "Habrían podido meterme a la cárcel, si me pescaban."
Totalmente de acuerdo con Pablo. Respecto de la oración "Si me pescaban me metían a la cárcel", cabe la posibilidad de que también sea interpretada como algo habitual o sistemático en el pasado (cada vez que me pescaban, me metían (¿a?) en la cárcel).

2a) "No tenía novio y me puedo imaginar que si lo tuviese no me lo hubiera dicho."
El embrollo que menciona Pablo radica en el conflicto entre "tenía" (que se refiere al pasado) y "tuviese" (que se refiere al presente). Si en lugar de "tenía" tuviéramos "tiene", la oración sería correcta: "Ella no tiene novio y, si lo tuviese, me lo habría/hubiera dicho."

2b) "Si fuera rico, no me hubiera ido a Australia."
En este punto disiento con Pablo. Creo que estamos frente a una condicional mixta, donde la condición se refiere al presente (una hipotética situación actual) y el resultado se refiere al pasado (una hipotética situación anterior). La idea es que NO **soy** rico, pues -- si lo fuera -- no me habría/hubiera ido a Australia (sino a otro destino). Pero la realidad es que me fui a Australia.

3) "Si fuera mi hija, quizá ya la habría matado."
De acuerdo con Pablo, pero reitero lo expresado en (2b).

4) "Tuvo suficiente leche para alimentar muchos niños más, si así lo hubiera deseado."
Esta oración me suena extraña. Para mí, sonaría mejor con "tenía": "Tenía suficiente leche para alimentar muchos niños más, (y lo habría hecho) si así lo hubiera deseado."

5a) "Iba a saltar, lo hubiera hecho si él no me lo impedía."
De acuerdo con Pablo. En el registro coloquial, es una oración correcta.

5b) "El sexo pudo salvarme si ella hubiese contestado: sí."
Para mí, esta oración es incorrecta. No encuentro relación con la oración (4), donde el indefinido se refiere a una situación por fuera de la condicional. En este caso, en mi opinión sólo podríamos decir: "El sexo me habría salvado/podría haberme salvado si ella hubiera/se contestado que sí."

6) "La verdad es que si hubiera seguido un momento más así me caigo de cabeza en la rayuela."
En el registro coloquial, es correcta. "caigo" es para mí un uso del presente histórico, utilizado en lugar del pasado para dar más realismo a la historia o anécdota que se narra: "Si hubiera seguido, me caía de cabeza."